# How can I arrange contorls on my webpage

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I need to arrange my web page controls in the following arrangment:

**header**

**leftcontent-content-rightContent**

**footer**

is there any control that helps me do that? not a table because it's not resizable?

Comment: Regardless of the merits of using tables for page layout - they are resizable.

Comment: Don't be discouraged, Lama. We can be kind of mean to newcomers here.

Comment: You can now use [tables for layout in HTML5](http://webdesign.about.com/od/tables/a/html5-tables-for-layout.htm) and don't have to lie awake at night wondering if your peers are chastising your html abilities.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement `div based` design and handle through `CSS`

Have a look at this http://www.winstonprakash.com/articles/netbeans/FixedPageLayout.html

http://www.colorplexstudios.com/articles/div_web_design_tutorial/

Comment: check the links in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished by using div tags and css. No special controls are required.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some examples that are easy to adapt and learn from.  http://www.code-sucks.com/css%20layouts/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a simple web layout control that can help you accomplish what you're designing easily without worrying about size of each panel, it helps you do that, exactly the way you want, here's the link:

http://www.zettacube.com/Products/ZeeWebLayout.aspx

and you can see online demo here:

http://demo.zettacube.com/Products/ZeeControls2/

and you can have a free license for **WebLayoutLite**.

Answer (score 0):

You should use div tag to part your web page into intended sections and design these divs in css file. Following example is for you.
in your page under the body tag write these divs--

```
enter code here
<body>
<div id="leftContent">
</div>
<div id="mainContent">
</div>
<div id="rightContent">
</div>
</body>
```

Then go to your css file (I assume you know about css file and its link to the html file)
    #leftcontent
        {
          background color:#fff;
          float:left;
          width:200px;
          height:800px;
        }
     #mainContent
        {
           background color:#fff;
           width:800px;
           height:800px;
        }
     #rightContent
        {
           background color:#fff;
           float:right;
           width:200px;
           height:800px;
        }